# How to exit a Battlefield 3 server after a match has finished?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a way to exit a multiplayer game of BF3 on the PS3 while waiting for the next match to start? I've tried the Start and  Circle buttons but neither does anything. I know you can exit with the PS button, but I would prefer another way.

Comment: Same for me on the xbox. Silly.

Comment: Honestly, I welcome this feature. Finally a way to punish rage quitters..

Comment: @Bora is it really rage quitting when someone is done playing multi and wants to get back to the campaign?

Comment: This "feature" BLOWs. You're not alone in your frustration.

Comment: A couple of things to keep in mind. Exiting once the new game has started effects your win/loss stats. Additionally, there are some timing issues with quitting out of the game where you can corrupt you saved game data. There are some pretty active discussions about the need for a clean exit on the Battlefield3 Forums.

Comment: I think DICE don't want you flipping about on servers, but I would have hoped then they could let me work on my customisations during intermission, rather than wait until the next game starts.

Comment: UPDATE: This has been patched in the latest update and now there is a "Quit" option in between games

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Correct, you can hit the PS button to exit, but that's it. Xbox users can hit the Xbox button.

For consoles, this has been a heavily requested feature for multiple versions of the franchise, but a proper way to exit between rounds has never been provided.

PC users can force the game closed, or hit ESC after the stats presentation to get an "exit game" prompt.

Comment: PC players can press ESC after the stats slideshow (and click "skip" to stop the slideshow) and get prompted to exit the game. Or ALT+F4 of course..

Comment: @JeffAtwood Didn't know that! Updated answer to reflect.

Comment: Which quit options will generate `Quit stats` on the battle log?

Comment: I believe it only generates "Quits" if you leave AFTER spawning in at least once. As long as you leave soon after the next server loads without spawning, you shouldn't get a quit (I have very few "quits", and so I'm pretty sure this is accurate)

Answer (score 4):

I havent tried this myself because i'm on wireless, but if you're using a wired internet connection you could try pulling it out when you're on the end of round screen. If you're disconnected it should exit you to the main menu saying you've 'lost connection to the server' and since you're between games it shouldn't affect your stats because you haven't quit a game...

Answer (score 1):

They fixed this in the latest patch. You can now push the "cancel" button (B on xbox, O on PS3) to exit the game at the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is push the PS button to exit to the main menu

Comment: Pushing the PS button usually allows you to leave the game completely, the user asked how he can go back without using the PS button