# How to quit Battlefield 3 without getting any "Quit" stats?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exit a Battlefield 3 server after a match has finished?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/how-to-exit-a-battlefield-3-server-after-a-match-has-finished)

As answered in this question: [How to exit a Battlefield 3 server after a match has finished?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33406/16052), the only option to quit the game between rounds is using the `PS`button and that does not seem to be the right way.

So when should one quit the game without getting any `Quit stats` which can be seen on the player stats on http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3?

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already asked this question [**here**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/how-to-exit-a-battlefield-3-server-after-a-match-has-finished). Using the PS button is the only way to do it (and the Xbox button for Xbox users). Apparently it's is a highly requested feature for console users.

Comment: That question is linked to in the original post, so the OP's already aware of it. This question seems slightly different, though I don't play BF3 so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: "How do I exit the game during a certain point" is different from "How do I trick the quit-tracking system to help pad my stats".